# Combine objects in JSON array if they share a property value using reduce, forEach or filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've searched on Stack for this question, but can't seem to find an answer.

I'm working on a project and trying to figure out how to reduce the number of objects in a JSON array and combine the `value`s from Objects that share a value with the `name`  property using `.reduce`, `.forEach`, or `.filter`, so that all the values with a given name will be paired together. I can do this with a `reduce` and an additional keyed object, but I'd like to keep this as a simple JSON array. I've tried a variety of permutations of `filter` and `reduce`, but they seem to be returning weird errors.

Here's the JavaScript code I'm working with:

```
//Json Data
var json = [{
    "name": "Value0",
    "value": "Sample0",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value0",
    "value": "Sample1",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value0",
    "value": "Sample2",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value0",
    "value": "Sample3",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value1",
    "value": "Sample4",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value1",
    "value": "Sample5",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value1",
    "value": "Sample6",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value1",
    "value": "Sample7",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value2",
    "value": "Sample8",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value2",
    "value": "Sample9",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value2",
    "value": "Sample10",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value2",
    "value": "Sample11",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value3",
    "value": "Sample12",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value3",
    "value": "Sample13",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value3",
    "value": "Sample14",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value3",
    "value": "Sample15",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value4",
    "value": "Sample16",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value4",
    "value": "Sample17",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value4",
    "value": "Sample18",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value4",
    "value": "Sample19",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value5",
    "value": "Sample20",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value5",
    "value": "Sample21",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value5",
    "value": "Sample22",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value5",
    "value": "Sample23",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value6",
    "value": "Sample24",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value6",
    "value": "Sample25",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value6",
    "value": "Sample26",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value6",
    "value": "Sample27",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value7",
    "value": "Sample28",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value7",
    "value": "Sample29",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value7",
    "value": "Sample30",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value7",
    "value": "Sample31",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value8",
    "value": "Sample32",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value8",
    "value": "Sample33",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value8",
    "value": "Sample34",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value8",
    "value": "Sample35",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value9",
    "value": "Sample36",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value9",
    "value": "Sample37",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value9",
    "value": "Sample38",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value9",
    "value": "Sample39",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value10",
    "value": "Sample40",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value10",
    "value": "Sample41",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value10",
    "value": "Sample42",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value10",
    "value": "Sample43",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value11",
    "value": "Sample44",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value11",
    "value": "Sample45",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value11",
    "value": "Sample46",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value11",
    "value": "Sample47",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value12",
    "value": "Sample48",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value12",
    "value": "Sample49",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value12",
    "value": "Sample50",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value12",
    "value": "Sample51",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value13",
    "value": "Sample52",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value13",
    "value": "Sample53",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value13",
    "value": "Sample54",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value13",
    "value": "Sample55",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value14",
    "value": "Sample56",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value14",
    "value": "Sample57",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value14",
    "value": "Sample58",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value14",
    "value": "Sample59",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value15",
    "value": "Sample60",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value15",
    "value": "Sample61",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value15",
    "value": "Sample62",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value15",
    "value": "Sample63",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value16",
    "value": "Sample64",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value16",
    "value": "Sample65",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value16",
    "value": "Sample66",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value16",
    "value": "Sample67",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value17",
    "value": "Sample68",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value17",
    "value": "Sample69",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value17",
    "value": "Sample70",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value17",
    "value": "Sample71",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value18",
    "value": "Sample72",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value18",
    "value": "Sample73",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value18",
    "value": "Sample74",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value18",
    "value": "Sample75",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value19",
    "value": "Sample76",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value19",
    "value": "Sample77",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value19",
    "value": "Sample78",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value19",
    "value": "Sample79",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value20",
    "value": "Sample80",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value20",
    "value": "Sample81",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value20",
    "value": "Sample82",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value20",
    "value": "Sample83",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value21",
    "value": "Sample84",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value21",
    "value": "Sample85",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value21",
    "value": "Sample86",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value21",
    "value": "Sample87",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value22",
    "value": "Sample88",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value22",
    "value": "Sample89",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value22",
    "value": "Sample90",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value22",
    "value": "Sample91",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value23",
    "value": "Sample92",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value23",
    "value": "Sample93",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value23",
    "value": "Sample94",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value23",
    "value": "Sample95",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value24",
    "value": "Sample96",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value24",
    "value": "Sample97",
    "truthy": false
}, {
    "name": "Value24",
    "value": "Sample98",
    "truthy": true
}, {
    "name": "Value24",
    "value": "Sample99",
    "truthy": false
}];
//removing irrelevant data items
json = json.map(function(item) {
    return {
        "name": item.name,
        "values": [item.value]
    };
});
//attempt at reduce function 

json.reduce(function(p, c) {
    if (p && p.name === c.name) {
        p.value.push(c.value);
    }
});
/*
//attempt at filter function
json = json.filter(function(item,i) {
if (i > 0 && item.name === json[i-1].name) {
json[i-1].value.push(item.name);
}
});

//forEach attempt /*
json = json.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  if (i > 0) {
    if (arr[i].name === arr[i - 1].name) {
      var pop = json.pop();
      json[i - 1].value.push(pop.value);
    }
  }
});
*/


console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
var json = [{
    "name": "Value0",
    "values": ["Sample0", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"]
}, {
    "name": "Value1",
    "values": ["Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6",  "Sample7"]
}
```

etc

Comment: What is supposed to happen to the `truthy` property? Your output has it in the second object, but why is it `true`?

Comment: It's supposed to disappear.

Comment: If it should disappear, you should modify your "Ideally" section, since you show it still being there for one of the objects. Also, can you assume that all the objects with the same name will be grouped together? i.e., will all of the "Value0" objects come first, then all the "Value1" objects, then all the "Value2" objects, etc? Or can they be mixed up?

Comment: I changed that. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but should work exactly as you asked

```
var newData = json.reduce(function (arr, currentValue){
    var index = false;
    arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
        if (item.name === currentValue.name && (item.truthy && currentValue.truthy || item.truthy === undefined && currentValue.truthy === false))     {
            index = i;
        }
    });

    if (index === false) {
        var newItem = {
            name: currentValue.name,
            values: [currentValue.value]
        };
        if (currentValue.truthy) {
            newItem.truthy = true;
        }
        arr.push(newItem);

        return arr;
    }

    arr[index].values.push(currentValue.value);

    return arr;
}, []);
```

also, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6xph0g9b/

Comment: A bit more convoluted than I imagined, but it works perfectly with a few modifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to think of this in two stages: 1) How do I filter the data I need? and then 2) How do I reduce it into the format that I want?

To accomplish #1, you use the `filter` function, which looks something like:

```
json.filter((el) => el.truthy)
```

This will return a new array with all of the elements that have a `truthy` value of `true`. Then, to thunk them down into a name/value pair, you run them through `reduce`:

```
json.filter((el) => el.truthy).reduce((seen, el) => {
  if(!seen[el.name]) seen[el.name] = []; // If our initial state doesn't have a key for this element's name, then initialize it to an empty array.
  if(seen[el.name].indexOf(el.value) === -1) // If our state doesn't already contain this element's value, then add it.
    seen[el.name].push(el.value);
  return seen; // Return state
}, {} /* Initial state is an empty object */)
```

This produces an object that has a key of el.name (eg: Value0) with a value of an array of all of Value0's `value` fields (eg: `Sample0` and `Sample2`).

Does that get you on the right track?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me in a JS fiddle. I can't use ECMAScript6, alas. https://jsfiddle.net/xax6xLuj/

Also, hopefully it's not too big of an ask, could you break down what the '!seen[el.name]' does? I've used versions of `!p[c]` a number of times in `reduce`, but I've never really understood what it does.

Comment: @litel The code in that JSFiddle isn't the code that I provided. In JSFiddle, you're assigning `json` to `undefined` because of `json = json.forEach(...)`. `forEach` runs a function on an array and returns nothing (undefined), so you're assigning json to undefined, then trying to run `reduce` off of undefined.

Comment: Also, I'm not looking to create a keyed object and convert that back into an array (that's not too hard). I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to combine the items in the JSON array without changing it into an object. I'm trying to reduce the number of steps.